# Make Physics more accurate

Tags: unity-game-engine

I make a 2D-game. In this game, I have a projectile, which I move the fires by myself like this:

```
void Update()
{
 gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(
  gameObject.transform.position.x + baseVelocity * Time.deltaTime,
  gameObject.transform.position.y + baseVelocity * Time.deltaTime,
  gameObject.transform.position.z);
}
```

And also, I use `void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)` to know when collisions occurs.

The problem is when game running on a weak phone with 30-FPS it won't detect collision, while same fire in an 60-FPS phone will collide.

I think this is because the fires move 2x more in 30-FPS phones.

One option was use `FixedUpdate()` method for moving fiers, but it gave me jerky movement, and I used `Update()` method for moving because it gives me smooth movement(in both of them I used Time.deltaTime).

Can you please suggest me how make more accurate while using smooth movement?
like move object in `Update()` method but check object position in more(offset) positions than where it is!

I forget to note that I changed the value of Fixed TimeStep to 0.01 for getting more accurate physics.

Thanks in advance.

edit:
I finally end up with using FixedUpdate() for move objects by myself, for so many reasons I can't use Physics engine, I set FixedUpdate TPS(tick per second) around 60 to some how be match with my 60 FPS Update (and still can't figure out why increase FixedUpdate TPS will make object movement jerky!).
And will keep this question open for finding better answer.

Comment: Use FixedUpdate. Can you show the code you used with FixedUpdate? It is not supposed to be jerky.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I said, using fixedupdate gave me a jerky experience, how handle this?

Comment: [Fixed Delta time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)

Comment: Check if it works. I'm gonna write a proper answer

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues my code is like my update one, should I use fixedDeltaTime instead of Time.deltaTime?

Comment: hmm... the docs say deltaTime becomes fixedDeltaTime inside FixedUpdate... maybe it wont make any change

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I tested again, with both Time.deltaTime and fixedDeltaTime inside fixedupdate, both gives me jerky moves.

Comment: take a look at this: https://www.unity3dtips.com/unity-fix-movement-stutter/

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues ok I will, but before, I forget to note that I changed Fixed TimeStep to 0.01 for getting more accurate physics. does it relate to have jerky movement in fixedupdat ?

Comment: Any reason for not using a rigidbody?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues yes, I should control, long to describe. But I used  rigidbody also for know about collisions trigger haha.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues again changed Fixed TimeStep value back to default one(0.0167), and jerky movement fixed(because fixedupdate now tick 60 times per second, like Update method), but it is not what I need, I need accurate physics(100 tick per second to calculate object offsets positions too) with smooth move(if it is possible together).

Comment: Use the [continuous collision detection mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html). Also by preferably letting the physics engine move your projectiles, rather than manually updating their position as you are now.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I finally end up with using FixedUpdate() for move objects by myself, for so many reasons I can't use Physics engine, I set FixedUpdate TPS(tick per second) around 60 to some how be match with my 60 FPS Update (and still can't figure out why increase FixedUpdate TPS will make object movement jerky!).
Thanks for your supports, and keep this question open for finding better answer.

Comment: @Draco18s yes it is on continuous mode, but for many reasons I'm not able to use Physics engine.

Comment: Option A: use the physics engine. Option B: stop complaining that the physics engine you aren't using correctly doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing the physics manually. The issue with manually updating the position is that you don't know about the position of your projectile between frames. Even if you were to use FixedUpdate, you could still be in the situation where two FixedUpdate calls cause your projectile to miss an object.

So instead of manually updating the position, you should use a RigidBody2D, with the collision detection set to "Continuous". A continuous collision detection will interpolate object collision in between physics update cycles, so you hit your target even at very high speeds. Also, this solution does not depend on frame rate.

Note that the above will only work if you don't manually update your positions yourself. That is because the physics engine uses velocity to calculate collision in between physics update cycles.

So instead of updating the position yourself (which is bad for physics), use forces instead.

Or alternatively, if you don't want to mess with forces, update the velocity instead:

```
GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().velocity = baseVelocity;
```

Comment: I finally end up with using FixedUpdate() for move objects by myself, for so many reasons I can't use Physics engine, I set FixedUpdate TPS(tick per second) around 60 to some how be match with my 60 FPS Update (and still can't figure out why increase FixedUpdate TPS will make object movement jerky!).
Thanks for your supports, and keep this question open for finding better answer.